# Tag Email Notifications

Tags: feature-request, tags, notifications

I help maintain [dynamoose](https://github.com/dynamoose/dynamoose) which has a [Stack Overflow tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dynamoose/info). However I've found it's difficult to keep up with Stack Overflow questions about this project.

One feature that would be really helpful and lead to me supporting users of [dynamoose](https://github.com/dynamoose/dynamoose) would be the ability to receive notifications or email alerts whenever someone posts a question with that tag. That way the chances of me seeing the question and writing an answer are higher.

I notice there is a button for `Question Subscriptions` under my profile settings, but clicking that takes me to a page that just says `No filter subscriptions` with no way to edit it. Maybe that is the feature I'm requesting?? But no idea how to modify those settings to get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

You were almost there when you clicked "Question Subscriptions". Just under the topbar there is a link to "Filtered Questions"

[image: filter question and filter subscriptions]

Click [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) and setup your tag filter for one or more sites.

You can set the email and how often you want to receive updates.

To edit a filter, use the [instruction I wrote over on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224557/158100). The instruction might also be helpful for your first set-up.

Comment: I've setup filters before and I was struggling to remember where to go to add a new one if I hadn't already got some setup... Might just be me, but that's not where I'd intuitively click to go add a filter... I'd have expected something in the subscriptions list itself with "add new subscription/filter" or something...

Comment: @JonClements yeah, I wrote that MSE answer after I found myself creating filter after filter. The whole UX around that feature can use some love.

Comment: It could be improved so much by simply changing it to "No filter subscriptions. [Add](https://stackexchange.com/filters)"