# How to add a tag to favorites on Stack Overflow mobile versions

Tags: discussion

I'm actually using the Stack Exchange app on my mobile phone and I would like to get a notification when a question is added to a certain tag.

How could I do that?

Comment: This still works: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397170/tag-email-notifications

Comment: @gnat How? Has the OP mentioned they use android? In any case, I can't see how they are related.

Comment: @10Rep as noted in the answers (and the question), the mobile apps have been retired. Questions about the mobile apps are therefore closed as duplicates of that question.

Comment: It's sad because the web site experience has deteriorated *significantly* on my older iPad, while the app keeps on working, tiny flaws and all. Resurrect the app!